# Updating the limitTo value on a specific nested ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to AngularJS and having to work on an app that has a section of nested ngRepeats such as this below.

```
<div class="title-bar" ng-repeat="orderType in someObj.orderTypes">
    <div class="inner-panel" ng-repeat="status in orderType.statuses">
        <p>{{status.Name}}</p>
        <div class="order-list" ng-repeat="order in status.Orders | limitTo:orderFilterLimit">
            <p>{{order.Stuff}}</p>
        </div>
        <button ng-show="(status.Orders.length > orderFilterLimit)" ng-click="loadMoreOrdersToList()">Load More</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `status.Orders` list can be quite large at times so I limit it. When a user wants to view more data for that specific section (which is enumerated by `status`) I add 3 to the `orderFilterLimit`. The problem is when I do this it is adding 3 to every single `.order-list` in the `.inner-pannel` element. Is there a way I can change the `orderFilerLimit` variable based on an id or class of the element it's attached to?

For context here is a super simple snippet of what `loadMoreOrdersToList()` is doing. 
https://jsbin.com/vapucixesa/1/edit?js

Comment: In which condition you wanted to change `limitTo` ?

Comment: I only want to change the limitTo on the element with class '.order-list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of declare the `orderFilterLimit` inside controller, You should have `scope` variable inside `ng-repeat` itself so that it ng-repeat element will have separate copy of `orderFilterLimit` because ng-repeat create a child scope on each iteration.

**Markup**

```
<div class="title-bar" ng-repeat="orderType in someObj.orderTypes" ng-init="orderFilterLimit = 3">
    <div class="inner-panel" ng-repeat="status in orderType.statuses">
        <p>{{status.Name}}</p>
        <div class="order-list" ng-repeat="order in status.Orders | limitTo:orderFilterLimit">
            <p>{{order.Stuff}}</p>
        </div>
        <button ng-show="(status.Orders.length > orderFilterLimit)" ng-click="orderFilterLimit = orderFilterLimit + 3">Load More</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm I'm getting a strange parsing error in my console. here's what the actual HTML looks like in my code. https://jsbin.com/woyiworigu/1/edit?html

Comment: try updates now..bdw what erroe you were getting in console.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much,  ng-init seems really useful, good one to know.

Comment: @Stavros_S Glad to hear that..Thanks :)